# How do you author Mac package to install without requiring admin privileges on Lion?

Tags: macos, installation, osx-lion, packagemaker

I'm trying to understand how to fix my Mac package developed in Packagemaker (that comes with Xcode 2.4.1) to install on OS Lion 10.7 without requiring admin privileges when it is being run as a standard user.  In 10.4, 10.5, 10.6, I was able to install this package as a standard user without admin privileges.  The contents of the package are installed into the user's home folder, so no additional privileges should be required.

Does anyone know how to do this? Or why the package would now require root permissions?

Or does anyone know if there are new restrictions in OS Lion that all installations require administrative privileges short of having an app bundle package that you just drag the app bundle to your home folder?

I looked on developer.apple.com, but haven't been able to find any information.

Brian

Comment: Why not try it with a more recent version of the Developer Tools? Xcode 2.4.1 is positively ancient.
PackageMaker 3.0.x can definitely create packages that don't need Admin privileges. There is a checkbox for this on the per-package Configuration tab.

Comment: Frankly, I'm amazed Xcode 2.4.1 runs at all on Lion.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely an issue with the trust of the software vendor, in this case, you.

http://www.bu.edu/infosec/howtos/bypass-gatekeeper-safely/

By default, Gatekeeper is set to ‘Mac App Store and identified developers.’  This means that a Mac running Mountain Lion will only run applications you have downloaded from the App Store or applications that have been signed with an official Apple Developer ID.  This helps to prevent malware from infecting your computer, as it makes it harder for malicious software posing as real applications to be installed by the user.

You have to sign your installation packages with your developer ID. Odds are, that version of packagemaker does not prompt you for it, or it is less obvious how to do it. See this about signing for lion. [Making OS X Installer Packages like a Pro - Xcode Developer ID ready pkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487596/making-os-x-installer-packages-like-a-pro-xcode4-developer-id-mountain-lion-re)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that it installs for just one user by default. If it does an install for all users root is required.